# JQueryUI Autocomplete collides with legacy code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-plugins

My issue is. I have jQueryUI in version 1.8.5 and lot and a lot of legacy source code in a project. In legacy code it happens that there is 3ple times registred plugin autocomplete for jquery. However jQueryUI is registring the very same plugin. So when I type into my javascript:

```
$('#some_id').autocomplete();
```

It's not actually a jQueryUI.

Any chance to explicit choose UI?

I tried such approach:

```
jQuery.fn.myautocomplete = jQuery.ui.autocomplete
```

And then to use in my code:

```
$('#some_id').myautocomplete();
```

But this does not work. (Well it was a blind shoot so I did not expect to much.)

Any suggestion how to workaround the problem.

**P.S.
Legacy code is blessed by the Pope and cannot be removed for next year or so.**

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. download jquery.ui without autocomplete
2. change jquery.ui source
3. change old plugin source

Comment: It seems poster is using autocomplete, no?

Comment: he said they have old plugin thet does the same thing. what's the reason to use both for one purpose?

Comment: But I want to use it. I want to use autocompleter not from my legacy code but from UI.

Comment: Because legacy code says 'autocomplete', but it means 'Im your god, bow and pray'. It's that type of reason.

Comment: 1. I need jqueryUI.autocomplete, I want to use it
2. source cannot be changed as its delivered from CDN
3. old plugin is out of reach (to much bc-issues)